# How do I loop through the rows in a column and count them using Python?

Tags: python, loops, count

I am trying to loop through column in an access table using Python. The column I have is sorted ascending.

I am trying to loop though the rows and when the value in the column changes, I want to get count of of all those values. In the example column below, the first group of values I want to count are the `M1`'s. When the next row changes to `M21`, I want to count the `M21`'s until it changes to `M23b` and so on.

I don't want to use an `if`/`else` statement, because there are a few hundred different possible values. I played around with the `groupby` function in the `itertools` module, but I haven't been able to solve the syntax to work in my example. I also tried a silly loop doing something like `if row != row.next(): do_something` but that blew up in my face. If anyone can suggest a work-around or show me a sample script that will do this for me, I'd appreciate it.

Example Column:

```
M1
M1
M1
M21
M21
M23b
M23b
S2
S23b
S23B
O1
O2
O2
O2
```

Comment: Are you sure the rows aren't an iterative object? Iterates terminate naturally in loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add printing in a loop doing other work, the following may be helpful:

```
from collections import Counter  # or defaultdict

col_counts = Counter()           # or defaultdict(int)

last_value = object()            # won't show up in table
for row in access_table:
    col_counts[row[field]] += 1
    if row[field] != last_value:
        print(col_counts[last_value])
        last_value = row[field]
    ...
    other_processing()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan. Between you and agf, I've put together a script that is almost working for me.

Answer (score 4):

Your intuition to use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) was correct:

```
for key, group in groupby(column):
    count = sum(1 for item in group) # Thanks JBernardo
    # the key is what is in the column, count is the number of items
```

Alternatively, if all you need is the counts, it's as simple as:

```
from collections import Counter # Python 2.7+

group_counts = Counter(column)
```

You can implement [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.counter) as:

```
from collections import defaultdict:

group_counts = defaultdict(int)

for item in column:
    group_counts[item] += 1
```

on older versions of Python.

Comment: Hey thanks agf! This pointed me in the right direction. See comments below.